# Unable to convert string to number on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, casting, amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I'm running this code in an Amazon Redshift query:

```sql
case when offer.disbursement_required = 'true' and  (json_extract_array_element_text(offer.disbursement_requirements, 2, true) :: numeric <> offer.amount  or (cast(json_extract_array_element_text(offer.disbursement_requirements, 2, true) :: numeric) is null or offer.amount  is null) 
        and not ((cast(json_extract_array_element_text(offer.disbursement_requirements, 2, true)) :: numeric) is null and offer.amount  is null) then 1
```

This is returning:

> [Code: 500310, SQL State: 0A000] Amazon Invalid operation: cannot cast type cstring to numeric;

and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be appreciated!! :)

Comment: What does `json_extract_array_element_text(offer.disbursement_requirements, 2, true)` contain?

Comment: {"maxAllocation": null, "minAllocation": 8000.00} @john

Comment: Then that is the cause of the error... How would `{"maxAllocation": null, "minAllocation": 8000.00}` convert to a numeric?

Comment: What is the best way to convert the minallocation value to a numeric in redshift?

Comment: You'd probably need to use another `json_extract_array_element_text()` to extract the `8000`.